# Ubuntu Support for ASUS Vivobook S14

Tags: 18.04, 18.10, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I have recently purchased my new laptop ASUS Vivobbok S14. i7, 8gb, 512gb version which comes with windows 10 pre installed. I am willing to install ubuntu 18 on this machine. Is there a support for my machine?? I have been reading many posts and came to know that there are backlight keyboard and wifi issue after the installation. And the battery backup is also reduced as compared to windows. I am a programmer, I need to upgrade only if there is full support/drivers available for my machine.

Comment: Eyeing one for Ubuntu as well. Would be good to get some info.